# HMAC-MD5 in pure lua

Tags: hash, lua, md5, hmac

I need to write a HMAC-MD5 algorithm in pure Lua..

I got this algorithm [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation)

```
function hmac (key, message)
    if (length(key) > blocksize) then
        key = hash(key) // keys longer than blocksize are shortened
    end if
    if (length(key) < blocksize) then
        key = key ∥ [0x00 * (blocksize - length(key))] // keys shorter than blocksize are zero-padded ('∥' is concatenation) 
    end if

    o_key_pad = [0x5c * blocksize] ⊕ key // Where blocksize is that of the underlying hash function
    i_key_pad = [0x36 * blocksize] ⊕ key // Where ⊕ is exclusive or (XOR)

    return hash(o_key_pad ∥ hash(i_key_pad ∥ message)) // Where '∥' is concatenation
end function
```

and I have the md5 code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292659/1137788). The md5 calculation function works correctly..

Implementing the algorithm in lua, so far I have the following code

```
local function hmac_md5(key,msg)
    local blocksize = 64

    if string.len(key) > blocksize then 
        key = calculateMD5(key)
    end 

    while string.len(key)<blocksize do 
        key = key .. "0"
    end 

    -- local o_key_pad = bit_xor((0x5c * blocksize),key) 
    -- local i_key_pad = bit_xor((0x36 * blocksize),key)

    return calculateMD5(o_key_pad..calculateMD5(i_key_pad..message))
end 

--calculateMD5 is the md5.Calc function in the Stackoverflow link specifed
```

I am stuck in the part where o_key_pad and i_key_pad are calculated.. do I just XOR the 2 values?  The python implementation in the wikipedia link had some weird calculations.. 
Please help!

Comment: never concatenate in a loop. for your code here just use `string.rep()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "⊕" is the symbol for "exclusive or".

- Remember: once you compute the final hash, **DO NOT** use an ordinary string comparison to check if a hash is correct.  This **WILL** allow attackers to sign arbitrary messages.
- Note that `0x5c * blocksize` is probably not what you are looking for, since that multiplies `0x5c` by `blocksize`.  You want to create an array of length `blocksize` containing `0x5c` in each position.
- Note that you must pad with zero bytes, not the character `"0"`.  So `key = key .. "0"` is wrong.  It should be `key = key .. "\0"`, or however you create NUL bytes in Lua.

Comment: Why not use ordinary string comparison?

Comment: @daurnimator: Ordinary string comparison allows attackers to sign arbitrary messages, under very reasonable assumptions and in real-world conditions.  Do **NOT** use ordinary string comparison for signature checks, it creates a VERY SERIOUS SECURITY HOLE.

Comment: how does it create a security hole? If it's about null bytes in the checksum, lua strings are stored with a length (and will not compare equal unless equal for all characters).

Comment: @daurnimator: It has nothing to do with NUL bytes in the HMAC, or what the result.  Simple string comparison leaks information about the difference between the two strings.  It's encoded in the timing of the string comparison, which takes a different amount of time depending on where the strings differ.  To answer your question, yes, this is exploitable in real-world conditions.  Yes, it is exploitable over a network, even with latency jitter.  No, the exploit does not take an unreasonable amount of time.  Yes, systems have been attacked this way.  Never write your own crypto library.

Comment: okay, still not a problem for lua though; strings are interned and are always a single pointer comparison.

Comment: @daurnimator: Are constructed strings interned automatically on creation?  Or does that only apply to string literals?

Comment: @daurnimator: Actually, scratch that.  If the strings are interned, then presumably this involves a string comparison in the Lua string table, which can be timed, which leaks information about the correct signature to attackers.  Presumably if Lua uses a hash table and you know what hash function it uses, the timing attack would be able to extract the position of items in the hash table as well as their lengths, and then do an attack against each one.  So if Lua does intern all strings, then it is **unsuitable** to use strings for storing hashes.

Comment: @daurnimator: Then if you store your HMAC in a string, your function is *probably* susceptible to a timing attack.  I hope you're not protecting something very important.

Comment: so the issue would be a timing attack on the string intern hash table? interesting... It's a state-global hash, so prior knowledge of contents is probably implausible? I suppose it is possible though

Comment: @daurnimator: You wouldn't need to know the contents of the hash table, just the hash function.  Using a timing attack you should be able to get the position of each entry in the hash table as well as its length.  You could then do a timing attack to discover the actual contents of the entire string table, with no prior knowledge.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22366/discussion-between-daurnimator-and-dietrich-epp)