# Pure Lua md5 using a byte array as input instead of string

Tags: hash, lua, cryptography, md5

I've been working in an algorithm that I found in this link: [Pure Lua implementation of md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083262/pure-lua-implementation-of-md5) to use in an embedded system, but it uses strings as input.

For my specific application, the hash need to receive an hex array like that: 85202599ee7e0165ee32be43336755595955544554554747.

How can I change the function bellow to calculate the hash using the array above?

```
function md5.Calc(s)
  local msgLen=string.len(s)
  local padLen=56- msgLen % 64
  if msgLen % 64 > 56 then padLen=padLen+64 end
  if padLen==0 then padLen=64 end
  s=s..string.char(128)..string.rep(string.char(0),padLen-1)
  s=s..leIstr(8*msgLen)..leIstr(0)
  assert(string.len(s) % 64 ==0)
  local t=md5.consts
  local a,b,c,d=t[65],t[66],t[67],t[68]
  for i=1,string.len(s),64 do
    local X=leStrCuts(string.sub(s,i,i+63),4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
    assert(#X==16)
    X[0]=table.remove(X,1) -- zero based!
    a,b,c,d=md5.transform(a,b,c,d,X)
  end
  local swap=function (w) return beInt(leIstr(w)) end
  return string.format("%08x%08x%08x%08x",swap(a),swap(b),swap(c),swap(d))
end

return md5.Calc("85202599ee7e0165ee32be43336755595955544554554747"); -- returns: cc238dfd3cf48d588714774efeaf9a1f
-- but I need a return like that calculated in https://cryptii.com/pipes/md5-hash: c7e9f863554dc9a410c414f8758b307d
```

Answer (score 0):

Lua strings can hold binary data: each "character" then is one byte. This is what is being used in above code. You can see that characters 128 (`0x80` or `0b10000000`) and zero are used for the padding.

So you should not change the above code at all; instead you should decode the hexadecimal string to a binary string and use that as input to above function.

You can find an interesting, concise method of hex decoding [here](https://gist.github.com/yi/01e3ab762838d567e65d).

Comment: And? Did you think this answer was useful? Please followup on your questions and indicate if answers are lacking detail or if they are acceptable by accepting them.